# Flutter ToggleButtons fill color doesn't match border in shape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create 3 toggleable buttons in one row with shared circular border.

```
class KnowledgeContentTypeChoice extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<IconData> icons = [Icons.mic, Icons.ondemand_video_rounded, Icons.article_outlined];
  final List<String> labels = ["Podcasty", "Vlogi", "Artykuły"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Material(
        elevation: 3,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            choiceButtons(icons, labels, context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Widget choiceButtons(List<IconData> icons, List<String> labels, BuildContext context) {
  return ToggleButtons(
    children: <Widget>[
      choiceButton(icons[0], labels[0]),
      choiceButton(icons[1], labels[1]),
      choiceButton(icons[2], labels[2]),
    ],
    onPressed: (int index) {
      Provider.of<KnowledgeContentTypeChoiceViewModel>(context, listen: false).currentIndex = index;
    },
    isSelected: context.watch<KnowledgeContentTypeChoiceViewModel>().isSelected,
    renderBorder: false,
    fillColor: Colors.blue,
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 40 *  fontRatio),
    selectedColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

Desired look:

[image: Expected look]

What I get:

[image: Outcome]

So the problem is that on the right the fill color goes out of circular border and is boxy.
How to fix it?

Comment: Can you include `choiceButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add clipBehavior like blow to container:

```
class KnowledgeContentTypeChoice extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<IconData> icons = [Icons.mic, Icons.ondemand_video_rounded, Icons.article_outlined];
      final List<String> labels = ["Podcasty", "Vlogi", "Artykuły"];
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,// add this
      child: Material(
        elevation: 3,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            choiceButtons(icons, labels, context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```